# Does command in shell script wait to complete execution of previous command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tomcat7

I want to make shell script to deploy .WAR on tomcat. since I need to build it everytime and building war takes bit time. I want to make whole procedure to be done using shell script. And as a newbie to linux I dont have much idea about it.

command 1 (to build war- takes some time to build).

command 2 (to depoy war to tomcat)

Does command 2 wait for execution of command 1 to get complete or it executes before whole execution.

Comment: That depends on the commands. If a program self-daemonizes, for instance, then it puts (at least some part of) itself in the background, thus (potentially) returning before it has completely executed.

Comment: However, if something isn't *intentionally* written to do such a thing, and isn't buggy in a manner comparable to how something might otherwise be intentionally behaving in this way (ie. with a stray `&`), then... it won't.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, command 2 will execute only after command 1.